# Hexdecimals in C

Tags: c, hex

I'm confused. Why in this program **a** gives me **0xFFFFFFA0** but **b** gives me **0xA0**? It's weird.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char a = 0xA0;
    int b = 0xA0;

    printf("a = %x\n", a);
    printf("b = %x\n", b);
}
```

Comment: Because the `char` is `signed` and so `0xA0` is negative.

Comment: No reason for confusion. Since you did not specify, the compiler is using its default signedness for `int` and `char`.

Comment: The `printf` format specifier `%x` does not know it was passed an `int` (second case) or a `char` which was promoted to `int` (first case), it works with the data it was given, in the context of expecting `unsigned int`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is char signed or unsigned by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/is-char-signed-or-unsigned-by-default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default type of `a` is `signed` in `char a = 0xA0;` and in any `signed data type` whether its `char of int` you should be careful of `sign bit`, if `sign bit` is `set` means number will be negative and store as `two's compliment` way.

```
char a = 0xA0; /* only 1 byte for a but since sign bit is set, 
              it gets copied into remaining bytes also */

a  =>                                     1010 0000
                                          |
                                        this sign bit gets copied
        1111 1111  1111 1111  1111 1111   1010 0000
         f    f      f   f     f    f      A    0
```

In case of `int b = 0xA0;` `sign bit(31st bit)` is `0` so what ever it contains i.e `0xA0` will be printed.

Comment: "By default type of `a` is signed" --> no,it is not.  It is like a `signed char` is OP's case, but that is not a _default_.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take this step-by-step.

---

```
char a = 0xA0;
```

`0xA0` in an *integer constant* with a *value* of 160 and type `int`.

In OP's case, a `char` is encoded like a `signed char` with an 8-bit range.  160 is more than the maximum 8-bit `char` and so assigning an out-of-range value to a some signed integer type is *implementation defined behavior*. In OP's case, the value "wrapped around" and `a` took on the value of 160 - 256 or -96.

```
// Try
printf("a = %d\n", a);
```

---

With `printf()` (a [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function)), `char a` it passed to the `...` part and so goes though the *usual integer promotions* to an `int` and retains the same value.

```
printf("a = %x\n", a);
// is just like
printf("a = %x\n", -96);
```

---

```
printf("a = %x\n", a);
```

With `printf()`, `"%x"` expect an `unsigned` or an `int` with a value in the non-negative range.  With `int` and -96, it is neither and so the output is **undefined behavior**.

A typical undefined behavior is this case is to interpret the passed bit pattern as an `unsigned`.  The bit pattern of `int` -96, as a 32-bit `int` is *0xFFFFFFA0*.

---

Moral of the story:

1. Enable a compile warnings.  A good compiler would warn about both `char a = 0xA0;` and `printf("a = %x\n", a);`
2. Do not rely on  undefined behavior.